# Not calling getlocalstorage from the function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, local-storage

Hello I'm trying to test my local storage functions but I don't know why is not calling the function or why it returns null.

Code

```
export const getRange = (type = '') => {
    switch (type) {
    case RANGE_SELECTION_TYPE.OPTIDRIVE:
        return getLocalStorageItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEYS.OPTIDRIVERANGE) || DATE_OPTIONS.LAST_30_DAYS
    case RANGE_SELECTION_TYPE.LOGBOOK:
        return getLocalStorageItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEYS.LOGBOOKRANGE) || DATE_OPTIONS.CURRENT_YEAR
    default:
        return DATE_OPTIONS.LAST_30_DAYS
    }
}
```

Test

```
test('should return the current value from the local storage from the opridrive selection', () => {
    setLocalStorageItem(type, DATE_OPTIONS.LAST_YEAR)
    expect(getRange(type)).toBe(DATE_OPTIONS.LAST_YEAR)
    removeLocalStorageItem(type)
})
```

So the function return the local storage value if it has but if not the default value, but it gets the default value when it shouldn't any suggestions?

P.S The program works!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your `type` is not being set correctly and when you getLocalStorage, it's not finding the right name of the local storage variable. I'd suggest debugging it by opening up Dev Tools. If you're using Chrome:

1. Ctrl + Shift + i (PC) or Cmd + Shift + i (Mac)
2. On the Dev Tools top bar, navigate to Application
3. On the left sidebar, expand Local Storage and click the endpoint in question (usually localhost)
4. See what your key is for the local storage variable and if that's set correctly.